# Using line.split until white space

Tags: python

Here is some of my code:

```
with open ('sampleID.txt', 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            if 'Sample ID:' in line:

                SID = line.split(':')[1]
```

The text file (sampleID.txt) has the following content:
Sample ID: 110715516102 ABC

Now the question is, how can I correct my code so that SID= 110715516102
The line.split is working but it includes a white-space and I want to avoid this.

Many thanks for all your help/support

Comment: I think the `strip()` function is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove extra spaces with the `strip()` function:

```
with open ('sampleID.txt', 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            if 'Sample ID:' in line:

                SID = line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line layout is always the same (ie, same number of spaces before the ID), just do:

```
SID = line.split()[2]
```

Comment: @MaximeLorant, index 1 will be the string 'ID:'.

Comment: Ah yeah, you split by spaces, not `:` ok. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is run the final string through the `strip()` function.

> **`str.strip([chars])`**
>
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. **If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.**

So your command within the loop would look something like this:

```
SID = line.split( ":" )[ 1 ].strip()
```

Reference:

- [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Answer (score 0):

Split it again on whitespace and take the first "word" to get `110715516102`:

```
SID = line.split(':')[1].split()[0]
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```